# Print string values from a delimited text in Unix

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to print the string from a delimited text file as

ABC_CAE_AAA_D_000_09

O/P
ABC_CAE

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I think the ABC_CAE is the expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply with ***cut*** command:

```
s="ABC_CAE_AAA_D_000_09"
cut -d'_' -f1-2 <<< $s
ABC_CAE
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this piece of code is working fine.

Comment: @Binay please remember to accept the answer if it solves your problem. Use the tick mark on the left to do so.